# Iterate through a vector of objects and find a variable that matches one pulled from a text file

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, iterator, stdvector

So I have a vector of objects

```
vector<Module*> moduleVector;
```

and I need to iterate through it and compare an attribute from the object to another attribute I'm pulling from a text file

I'm using an `ifstream` and `getLine()` to store the element that needs to be compared to the object's attribute (`fileD` is the opened file, `markModId` is the string variable)

```
getline(fileD, markModId, ' ');
```

But I am unsure of how I can refer to the object's attributes in an iterator. So my question is,

**how do I compare the attribute from the file to the object using an iterator?**

For reference here is my object constructor (id is the attribute I want to compare)

```
Module::Module(string id, string title, string lecturer, int 
courseworkWeight)
{
   code = id;
   name = title;
   lect = lecturer;
   cwWeight = courseworkWeight;
   exMark = 0; //ex mark initialised as 0
   /*
   Map to store coursework marks
   */
   map<string, float> CWmarks;
   //cwMarks.clear(); //cw marks map cleared
   //create a map that stores
}
```

And `exMark` is the attribute that needs to be added to the object. All attributes in the `Module` constructor are `private`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I compare the attribute from the file to the object using an
>   iterator?

**Short answer**: Suppose you have an iterator `std::vector<Module*>::iterator iter` you can access the public members of `Module` class like:

```
(*iter)->/*public member*/;
```

---

**Long answer**: First of all, you need a getter for private member `id` and one setter for `exMark`, by which you can get the `id` of each `Module` and compare to the id from the file and then set its  `exMark` to some value.

```
std::string getId()const { return code; }
void setExMark(const double newMark) { exMark = newMark; }
```

If you want to change the first true instance of `Module`, you can use [`std::find_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) for finding the `Module`:

```
std::string idFromFile = "two";
auto Condition = [&idFromFile](Module* element){ return element->getId() == idFromFile; };
auto iter = std::find_if(moduleVector.begin(), moduleVector.end(), Condition);

if(iter != moduleVector.end())
     (*iter)->setExMark(10.0);  // see this
   // ^^^^^^^^^
```

<kbd>**[See a sample code here](https://www.ideone.com/d2lpDB)**</kbd>

For multiple instances you can do:

```
for(auto iter = moduleVector.begin(); iter != moduleVector.end(); ++iter)
      if ( (*iter)->getId() == idFromFile)
         (*iter)->setExMark(10.0);
```

---

**Note**:  In modern C++ you can use [smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/smart_pointers), instead of raw pointers, which will delete the objects automatically as it goes out of scope.

Comment: You are assuming that `code` and `exMark` are private and not public to begin with. The OP didn't show the declaration of `Module`

Comment: @JeJo I implemented the getters and setters, however for some reason exMark is still being displayed as zero.

Comment: @Sean Did you check the output of: this:https://www.ideone.com/d2lpDB ? However, incase of changing all matches of `id` you need to iterate through the vector and set the exMark. Something like this : https://www.ideone.com/O3xaWb

Comment: @JeJo Hi Jejo, I checked and tried both ways but it is still outputting exMark as 0

Comment: @Shaun It should work. I think the problem is with the string or variable from file to which you are comparing `Module`'s member variables. Try to debug(or print the  output data of the file) the code and see what are the values you are getting from file. (I asume that the the member variables are okay)

Comment: @Jejo I printed the variables from the file and the first few are appearing as Hexadecimal numbers and the rest are somehow in the wrong order

Comment: @Shaun Good. Now you know where you have the problem, which you can  solve by stepping through with the debugger. I hope that I have answered for what you asked in the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178483/discussion-between-jejo-and-shaun).

Answer (score 1):

Simply dereference the iterator to access its `Module*` pointer, then you can access the object using `operator->` however you want, eg:

```
for (std::vector<Module*>::iterator iter = moduleVector.begin(), end = moduleVector.end(); iter != end; ++iter)
{
    Module *m = *iter;
    if (m->code == markModId)
        m->exMark = ...;
}
```

Or, if you are using C++11 or later, let the compiler handle the iterator for you:

```
for (Module *m : moduleVector)
{
    if (m->code == markModId)
        m->exMark = ...;
}
```

Or, use a lambda with one of the standard iteration algorithms, eg:

```
std::for_each(moduleVector.begin(), moduleVector.end(),
    [&](Module *m)
    {
        if (m->code == markModId)
            m->exMark = ...;
    }
);
```

If you are only interested in updating 1 Module, then break the loop when the the desired Module is found:

```
for (std::vector<Module*>::iterator iter = moduleVector.begin(), end = moduleVector.end(); iter != end; ++iter)
{
    Module *m = *iter;
    if (m->code == markModId)
    {
        m->exMark = ...;
        break; // <-- add this
    }
}
```

```
for (Module *m : moduleVector)
{
    if (m->code == markModId)
    {
        m->exMark = ...;
        break; // <-- add this
    }
}
```

```
auto iter = std::find_if(moduleVector.begin(), moduleVector.end(),
    [&](Module *m) { return (m->code == markModId); });
if (iter != moduleVector.end())
{
    Module *m = *iter;
    m->exMark = ...;
}
```